# Transformation of Expectation of Summation

Tags: probability, statistics

Can I perform that $$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^{n}E[X_i]$$ if $X_i$ is not i.i.d.?

In other words, can I move the summation inside expectation out in any situation?

Also, what about variance $Var(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)$? Is it the same as expectation?

Comment: Yes, this feature of expectation is not related to independent or dependent of random variables.

Comment: And _No,_ It is not the same for variance, unless the $X_i$ are uncorrelated. Suppose $X \equiv Y.$ Then $Var(X + Y) = Var(2X) = 4Var(X),$ which is not the same as the incorrect $Var(X + Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) = 2Var(X).$

Comment: Just a technical reminder that you require each expectation exist. You may have $E[X - X] = E[0] = 0$ but $E[X]$ itself does not exist, say $X$ is  Cauchy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

$$\mathbb{E}[A+B] = \mathbb{E}[A]+\mathbb{E}[B]$$ doesn't require $A$ and $B$ to be i.i.d.

The result can be proven by induction.

Also, edit to answer the added question:$$\operatorname{Var}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right] = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \operatorname{Cov(X_i,X_j})=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}(X_i)\right)+2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j = i+1}^n\operatorname{Cov(X_i,X_j)}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!
What about $Var$?